# Password validation using Java regex fails

Tags: java, regex

My requirements include among other things to validate for the password input to include one of the following characters only once. !@#$%^&*()_+=?~

To accomplish that I wrote the following:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("(?=.*[a-z])");
builder.append("(?=.{1}[!@#$%^&*()_+=?~])");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(builder.toString());
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

if(matcher.matches){
    return True;
}
```

But this always fails when I pass valid input in my unit test. I am new to regex.

Comment: Does your password also have a length requirement?

Comment: @anubhava But that doesn't also make a positive assertion for the presence of one symbol character.

Comment: Length is actually min 12 and it works fine.If I remove ? from the requirement, my test passes.I have one special character requirement.

Comment: Is there a max character limit also?

Comment: No max characters.

Comment: ok then `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=[^!@#$%^&*()_+=?~]*[!@#$%^&*()_+=?~][^!@#$%^&*()_+=?~]*$).{12,}$` should work.

Comment: [here] (https://howtodoinjava.com/regex/how-to-build-regex-based-password-validator-in-java/) you can see more on pattern matching. Everything should be in braces like `((?=.*[a-z])(?=.{1}[!@#$%^&*()_+=?~]))` but you are giving like this `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.{1}[!@#$%^&*()_+=?~])` without outer braces.

Comment: @anubhava, that was perfect solution. I really appreciate your help. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @Mandy8055: Thanks. In terms of performance a negative character class `[^a-z]*` will be fastest. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 lookahead assertions:

```
^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^!@#$%^&*()_+=?~]*[!@#$%^&*()_+=?~][^!@#$%^&*()_+=?~]*$).{12,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MmCRI5/2)

Note that in `.matches()` method start & end anchors are automatically implied in a given regex.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])`: Positive lookahead to make sure we have at least one lowercase letter
- `(?=[^!@#$%^&*()_+=?~]*[!@#$%^&*()_+=?~][^!@#$%^&*()_+=?~]*$)`: Positive lookahead to make sure we have **ONLY** one of the given special character.
- `.{12,}`: Match min 12 of any characters
- `$`: End